# How to keep ordered list using 'set'?

Tags: python, list, set

I want to be able to keep the order of the list when it compares. Notice when I compare list1 with list2, it returns me 8 then 7 (reverse). How do I have it maintain the order?

```
>>> list1 = ['1','2','3','4','7','8'] 
>>> list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
>>> list(set(list2) - set(list1))    
['5', '6']
>>> list(set(list1) - set(list2))    
['8', '7']
```

Comment: Do you want the order as given in the list or do you want the result of the set difference sorted?

Comment: Right, so I want the order to be maintained from the original list given. In other words, the expected output should be ['7', '8'] instead... However, I need to to be applied to strings as well (maintain order of list) and not "sorted" numerically.

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985297/how-to-xor-two-lists-in-python/47985524#47985524

Answer (score 7):

An `OrderedDict` makes a good substitute for an order-preserving set, since the keys views are set-like:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list1 = ['1','2','3','4','7','8'] 
>>> list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(list1).keys() - OrderedDict.fromkeys(list2).keys()
{'7', '8'}
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(list2).keys() - OrderedDict.fromkeys(list1).keys()
{'5', '6'}
```

Please note that subtracting keys views returns a standard set, which is arbitrarily ordered.  Using list-comprehensions makes the ordering reliable, and we're still *O(n)*:

```
>>> od1 = OrderedDict.fromkeys(list1)
>>> od2 = OrderedDict.fromkeys(list2)
>>> [k for k in od1 if k not in od2]
['7', '8']
>>> [k for k in od2 if k not in od1]
['5', '6']
```

When the standard dict is order-preserving (Python 3.7+ or CPython 3.6+) you can achieve the same result using `dict.fromkeys` instead of `OrderedDict.fromkeys`.

Comment: in Python 3.6+, dict insertions are ordered, so you can use `dict.fromkeys()`

Comment: @pylang Not quite. Python 3.7+ or CPython 3.6+.

Comment: The set difference solution doesn't work. The order of the result is random.

Comment: @Aran-Fey  I couldn't find a Python version where the `odict_keys` view returned randomly (though it might be *unspecified*). Regardless, I don't present it as a full solution, just a demonstration that the views are set-like.

Comment: @Aran-Fey.  True, but I believe that detail is a bit pedantic.  I suspect the `python` tag intrinsically refers to the CPython implementation.  Regardless, thanks.

Comment: @wim The problem is that subtracting two odict_keys returns a regular set with arbitrary ordering.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
list1 = ['1','2','3','4','7','8'] 
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']

set1 = set(list1)  # convert to set for faster membership testing
result = [x for x in list2 if x not in set1]
# result: ['5', '6']
```

This will, however, include duplicate elements:

```
>>> list1 = [1]
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 2]
>>> set1 = set(list1)
>>> [x for x in list2 if x not in set1]
[2, 2]
```

If duplicates aren't desired, simply transform the list comprehension into a loop and keep track of all elements that you've already encountered:

```
list1 = [1] 
list2 = [1, 2, 2]

set1 = set(list1)
result = []

for x in list2:
    if x in set1:
        continue

    result.append(x)
    set1.add(x)

# result: [2]
```

Comment: What if original lists contain duplicates?

Comment: @Akavall You'll have to ask the OP what should happen in that case.

Comment: It looks to me like OP wanted a set difference with order preserved.

Comment: @Akavall  Then you do a similar thing with a `collections.Counter` instead of a set.

Comment: Looks good, I wasn't the one who downvoted, so I can't undo that!

Comment: Yes, the list may contain duplicates. Would this still work?

Comment: @python_newbie I've shown how it handles duplicates. If the output isn't to your liking, please explain how you want duplicates to be handled.

Comment: sorry! I see it now.. why must you convert to set? you mentioned "faster membership testing".. may you please elaborate?

Comment: @python_newbie Sets have constant-time O(1) membership testing because they simply compute the value's hash and look it up. Membership testing with a list however is O(n) because it has to iterate through the entire list until it finds a match. See also [How efficient/fast is Python's 'in'? (Time Complexity wise)](//stackoverflow.com/q/12905513).

Comment: @Aran-Fey: ok you're too smart for me but thanks for the explanation and solution! It works...

Comment: @python_newbie he means looking in a set is easier to find an item (a postman can find you by your "address") vs. a list is slower, where every element must be searched left to right until a match is found (the postman knocks door to door to find you).

Answer (score 1):

While this does not use the `-` operator for sets, it does preserve the order of the original list.

```
list1 = ['1','2','3','4','7','8'] 
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
set_list2 = set(list2)
result = []
for item in list1:
    if not item in set_list2:
        result.append(item)
        set_list2.add(item) # to avoid duplicates in result
print(result)
# ['7', '8']
```

Comment: I think updating `set_list2` to keep track of items added to `result`, and therefore not adding same element more then once is more in the spirit of OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension instead to find the difference. Here is how you do it:
`[x for x in list1 if x not in list2]` which will yield `['7', '8']`

And you can do `[x for x in list2 if x not in list1]` which will yeild `['5', '6']`

And if original list contains duplicates, you can use `[x for x in list1 if x not in list2 and list1.count(x) == 1]`

Answer (score 0):

A 'set' by definition is unordered. If you'd like to sort the elements, try using a list operation. You can use [setdiff1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) from numpy, for example:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = ['1','2','3','4','7','8'] 
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
new_list_one = np.setdiff1d(list2, list1)
new_list_two = np.setdiff1d(list1, list2)

print(new_list_one) ['5' '6']
print(new_list_two) ['7' '8']
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most naive approach:

```
def ordered_diff(a, b):
    seen = set(b)
    result = []
    for ele in a:
        if ele not in seen:
            result.append(ele)
            seen.add(ele)

    return result     


list1 = ['1','2','3','4','7','8','7','8'] 
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','5','6']

print ordered_diff(list1, list2)
print ordered_diff(list2, list1)
```

Result:

```
['7', '8']
['5', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, just use a list comprehension:

```
[x for x, y in zip(b, a) if x != y]
# ['5', '6']

[x for x, y in zip(a, b) if x != y]
# ['7', '8']
```

In general, consider [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) (vs. `zip`), particularly with lists of differing lengths.